# Загрузка переменной на сервер Cro и отдача переменной на страницу сайта

Tags: сервер, запрос, get

Сразу уточню, чтобы в меня не кидали камни.
В серверном программирование я не шарю. А точнее.

Сервер используемый в работе - Cro (Cro::HTTP)

Модуль (или скрипт ) - web.Raku

Есть простая страница HTML с Javascript. По кнопке, со страницы сайта отправляется запрос GET (javascript) на сервер. Далее сервер отдает ответ на страницу сайта, в виде переменной test2, а конкретно значение 999. В запросе test2=999, ну для видения работы механизма процесса. Значение 999 приходит в ответе responce и после обработки выводится в Label_1 на страницу сайта.

Далее в запросе убираю =999, т.е. остается строка

```
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:10000/articles2?test2", true);
```

Далее есть консоль, она делает запрос через curl на сервер и отдает переменную test2, а конкретно значение 77177 (для тестирования). Теперь запрос curl похож на запрос GET со страницы сайта. Эти оба запроса работают самостоятельно.
И тут тупик. На странице сайта при запросе переменной test2 значение не поступает с сервера.

1. Сервер - он хранит у себя переменную ?
   Если да, то как: база данных с ячейками, просто переменная ?
2. Сервер - не хранит, а перенаправляет переменную (то есть она сразу улетает на мой сайт) ?
   Если да, то как ?

*Далее вырезки кода*

Запрос со страницы сайта:

```
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
      {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
          {
              myFunction(this.responseText)
          }
      }      
      xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:10000/articles2?test2=999", true);      
      xhttp.send();
```

обработка ответа на странице сайта:

```
function myFunction(data) 
      {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          //alert(data);
          //alert("data");
          // переменной d - присваиваем данные ответа
          d = data;
          document.getElementById("label_1").innerHTML = d;
      }
```

Строка в консоли:
curl http://127.0.0.1:10000/articles22?test2=77177

Собственно серверная часть, обработка запросов:

```
 my $application = route {      
        get -> 'articles22', :$test2! {
            content 'text/html', "$test2";
        }
    }
```

P.S.
сайт документации https://cro.services/ - читаю с Гугл-переводчиком.